# Parsing FIX protocol message from log file in regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, fix-protocol

I need to extract all the FIX messages from a large log file and which might have more then 10000 to 20000 FIX protocol messages. FIX protocol messages which I am expecting to fetch would be starting with `8=FIX` and ending with `|10=` some CheckSum value which could be any value then followed by delimiter `'|'`.

e.g. `8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111|`

Currently, I am using this pattern for regex

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("8=FIX(.*?)10=(.*?)|");`

But in above pattern, I am only able to extract message till `10=` but not the checksum value and also there could be a scenario where some FIX message custom tag would be like 8410=TEST| as below:

`8=FIXT.1.1|9=73|35=0|34=560|49=RTNSFIXUAT|8410=TEST|52=20140403-01:50:21|56=TR_UAT_VELOCITY|1128=8|10=206|`

And here above, I would get the value

> "8=FIXT.1.1|9=73|35=0|34=560|49=RTNSFIXUAT|84" (**X - I want complete messages till tag 10 checksum value 206**)

Please find the log file snippet as follows:

```
>02-04-14 11:38:33.559|QFJ Message Processor|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|quickfix.outgoing: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=1731|49=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:33.557|56=REPOFIXUAT|10=147|
02-04-14 11:38:34.713|SocketConnectorIoProcessor-1.0|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|quickfix.incoming: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|1128=8|49=REPOFIXUAT|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:34|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|453=4|448=ZERO|452=3|447=D|448=MBY2|452=1|447=D|448=LMEB|452=16|447=D|448=DOR|452=11|447=D|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|150=F|32=50000000.00|15=GBP|1056=88330000.00|31=1.6666|194=1.6654|195=0.0012|64=20140415|63=B|60=20140402-11:07:33|75=20140402|1057=N|460=4|167=FOR|65=OR|55=GBP/USD|10=111|
02-04-14 11:38:35.004|QFJ Message Processor|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|Received FIX application message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111|
```

Comment: Use the `cut` command available in NIX systems or use it in cygwin on windows. Maybe a 2 minute job.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retain:

- Everything after `8=FIX` but before `|10=...`
- Also the value in `|10=value|`

Here's an example:

```
String input = ">02-04-14 11:38:33.559|QFJ Message Processor|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|quickfix.outgoing: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=1731|49=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:33.557|56=REPOFIXUAT|10=147|\r\n"
                       + "02-04-14 11:38:34.713|SocketConnectorIoProcessor-1.0|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|quickfix.incoming: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|1128=8|49=REPOFIXUAT|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:34|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|453=4|448=ZERO|452=3|447=D|448=MBY2|452=1|447=D|448=LMEB|452=16|447=D|448=DOR|452=11|447=D|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|150=F|32=50000000.00|15=GBP|1056=88330000.00|31=1.6666|194=1.6654|195=0.0012|64=20140415|63=B|60=20140402-11:07:33|75=20140402|1057=N|460=4|167=FOR|65=OR|55=GBP/USD|10=111|\r\n"
                       + "02-04-14 11:38:35.004|QFJ Message Processor|input/REPOFIXInput1|INFO|Received FIX application message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111|";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("8=FIX(.+)(?<=\\|)10=(.+?)(?=\\|)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        System.out.println("\t" + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("\t" + m.group(2));
    }
```

**Output**

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=1731|49=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:33.557|56=REPOFIXUAT|10=147
    T.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=1731|49=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:33.557|56=REPOFIXUAT|
    147
8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|1128=8|49=REPOFIXUAT|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:34|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|453=4|448=ZERO|452=3|447=D|448=MBY2|452=1|447=D|448=LMEB|452=16|447=D|448=DOR|452=11|447=D|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|150=F|32=50000000.00|15=GBP|1056=88330000.00|31=1.6666|194=1.6654|195=0.0012|64=20140415|63=B|60=20140402-11:07:33|75=20140402|1057=N|460=4|167=FOR|65=OR|55=GBP/USD|10=111
    T.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|1128=8|49=REPOFIXUAT|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|52=20140402-11:38:34|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|453=4|448=ZERO|452=3|447=D|448=MBY2|452=1|447=D|448=LMEB|452=16|447=D|448=DOR|452=11|447=D|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|150=F|32=50000000.00|15=GBP|1056=88330000.00|31=1.6666|194=1.6654|195=0.0012|64=20140415|63=B|60=20140402-11:07:33|75=20140402|1057=N|460=4|167=FOR|65=OR|55=GBP/USD|
    111
8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111
    T.1.1|9=449|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|
    111
```

**Notes**

- This example is not performance-optimized.
- You probably want to remove the "multi-line" flag to this `Pattern`, and treat each line separately with a constant `Pattern`
- If you do so, you will have to reinitialize a `Matcher` for each line, but you can probably call `find` in an `if` statement instead of a `while` statement, assuming you have one log per line
- Storing matched values is up to you

Comment: Thanks Mena, the above sample method worked for me but if I am processing through my log file its not giving the results. I believe its due to `\r\n` which you have explicitly added to above code to work for pattern matching.

And also, as I had written in my question that I need to process 10 to 20K FIX messages from file. so in this case, I need to write ` m.group(), m.group(1), m.group(2)` till 20K.

Please advise on above.

Regards

Comment: @Ankit as mentioned in the notes, the `Pattern` you want will probably not have the multi-line flag (just remove it) as you'll be processing your files line by line. Also mentioned: storing the matched values is up to you, whether you put them in a file, database, or (riskier due to size) store them in memory. As you can see you only really need groups 1 and 2; main group is the whole match.

Comment: Many Thanks once again but as of now I am not concerned about saving those message. I was still not getting the expected messages from logs by using above regex(Might be I am missing something) however I tried `8=FIX(.*?)(?<=)~10=(.*?)~` regex expression after spending sometime over net on Regex tutorial and which worked for me. 

Please suggest it will work for all the scenario or I am missing any particular one as per my above requirement because I am new to regex world.

Answer (score 0):

So its a good idea to persist all your FIX messages to database, once they're "dealt with" and avoid all this.

Comment: Database will be much much slower than writing to a file.

Comment: yes, so use message broker to get the work done, then persist for the reports required here.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem that I was using `"|" (pipe)` as delimiter in FIX message but it was also present in the logs comments (`02-04-14 14:30:45.139|QFJ Timer|input/FIXInput1|INFO|Sending FIX session message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=71|35=0|34=2072|49=UAT|52=20140402-14:30:45.139|56=FIXUAT|10=140|
02-04-14 14:30:45.141|QFJ Timer|input/FIXInput1|DEBUG|FIX message as XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><message>`) which was not processing the pattern till the end of `10=checksum`and now after making the delimiter between the FIX message tag to `"~" (tilde)` in my above pattern i.e.'8=FIX(.*?)(?<=)~10=(.*?)~' then it worked for me which is similar to REGEX provided by you as solution above.